# Laravel keep the session whenever the user is logged in

Tags: php, laravel

My users can tick the box "remember me", which means they'll be logged in *forever*. When they login I fill a Custom Session with their Subscription data and this works fine.

The problem is when they turn off their computer, come back the next day and instead of going through the Login Process again, they automatically join the "Dashboard" page (because they are already logged in, through the "remember me" process) and at this point my Custom Session does not exists (and triggers error).

In App > Http > Controllers > Auth > LoginController.php I have the `Login` function that overrides the original Laravel function, like such:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email','password' => 'required']);
    
    if (Auth::guard()->attempt($this->credentials($request), $request->remember))
    {
        $subscription = \App\Models\Subscriptions::where('id', \Auth::user()->subscription_id)->first();
        
        \Session::put('subscription',
        [
            'id' => $subscription->id,
            'name' => $subscription->name,
            // etc..
        ]);
    }
}
```

For me, this is not the correct place to put my Custom Session, but I don't know where to put it.

**Question**: where should I create my Global Sessions that must be initialized/created whenever the User is logged in / navigating in any page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

To keep my session data always up-to-date and taking in consideration the "remember me" tickbox, I used the Laravel Authenticate Middleware to create my logic. Since `auth` is being called in every route, it seems to me the best option.

To avoid multiple database calls, I check if the session exists and only if not is when I create the session.

`App > Http > Middleware > Authenticate.php` [the documentation](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.html#method_handle) allows us to use an existing function called `handle`.

```
public function handle($request, \Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    if (!\Session::get('subscription'))
    {
        // Apply code logic 
    }
    
    // Same logic as the original function https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php#L40    
    $this->authenticate($request, $guards);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of suggestions on improving your code. Your login function should just log the user in and that's it.

### Use relationships!

From what I can see, you are storing subscription id in the users table. Why not store user id in subscriptions table? That way, you can create a relationship between those two tables, where user will have only one subscription (laravel's `hasOne()` method), and subscription will belong to the user (laravel's `belongsTo()` method). Read Laravel's documentation about Eloquent Relationships [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships).

### Don't use session if you don't need it!

If you implement the above relationships, accessing your users subscription data will be as easy as calling `$user->subscription`. Since it is so easily retrievable, there is no need to store anything in session, as you can get your authenticated user with `Auth::user()` whenever (controller, blade, ...).

#### If you still want to stick with session...

You can try to extend the session's lifetime like [this](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-increase-session-lifetime-in-laravelexample.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20increase,timeout%2C%20expire_on_close%20and%20encrypt%20etc.), and set it to i.e. 14 days, or 20 years, so it will never expire.

Comment: Multiple users belong to a subscription and not the other way around, that's why it's on the users table. I don't want to use `$user->subscription` because this means every time a page is refreshed a query is being done to the database.

Comment: Still, you should use relationships, where User hasOne() subscription, and subscription hasMany() users, instead of writing a query as above. Also, if you don't want to query the database each time, you can use Laravel's Cache to cache the results for some period of time. That query should be super fast and it should not worry you that the database is queried every time for that :)

Answer (score -1):

Put your code in the AppServiceProvider.php
Write it inside the boot() method.
The codes in the boot method will always be checked first.
Read more on laravel documentation.